# I'm getting "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SoapClient::SoapClient() Stack trace: #0 SoapClient->SoapClient(NULL, Array) #1 "

Tags: php, soap

I'm getting with my hotel provider:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SoapClient::SoapClient() Stack trace: #0 SoapClient->SoapClient(NULL, Array) #1

I managed once to make a booking but then start getting this message.

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: 'uri' option is required in nonWSDL mode in /home/fanzy44/public_html/FLuxuryWorld.com/HotelCollection/wp-content/themes/agility-child/single-bookhotel.php:1983
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/fanzy44/public_html/FLuxuryWorld.com/HotelCollection/wp-content/themes/agility-child/single-bookhotel.php(1983): SoapClient->SoapClient(NULL, Array)
>   #1 /home/fanzy44/public_html/FLuxuryWorld.com/HotelCollection/wp-includes/template-loader.php(47): include('/home/fanzy44/p...')
>   #2 /home/fanzy44/public_html/FLuxuryWorld.com/HotelCollection/wp-blog-header.php(16): require_once('/home/fanzy44/p...')
>   #3 /home/fanzy44/public_html/FLuxuryWorld.com/HotelCollection/index.php(17): require('/home/fanzy44/p...')
>   #4 {main} thrown in /home/fanzy44/public_html/FLuxuryWorld.com/HotelCollection/wp-content/themes/agility-child/single-bookhotel.php on line 1983

Comment: Do you seriously expect us to find out what's wrong without a piece of code?

Comment: Gordon, is this error coming from your code or an external source?  There's not much you can do about external errors other than report them to the service's maintainer.

Comment: SOAP is a pain in the ass to set up.. I speak from experience, I advise using something like JSON...

Comment: Jeffrey (i'm sorry I'm new) here is some code

Comment: {
       // create SOAP client object
        //Hotels Pro Booking URL
 
           $client = new SoapClient($hotelProBookingURL, array('trace' => 1));

      try
      {
        // Create rooms arrays
        $rooms[] = array();
        
       
        // take out the value of rooms
        $str_roomData = explode('rooms', $valRoomAdultChild);
        // total rooms will be in $str_roomData[0]
        
        if ($str_roomData[0] > 1)
        {
            $isMultipleRooms = true;
            $requestedRoom = $str_roomData[0];
        }

Comment: Gordon, mind adding your code directly to your question instead of placing it in a comment?

Comment: @Gordon looks like the problem is you haven't actually declared `$hotelProBookingURL` and set its value to your WSDL.

Comment: @Gordon, additionally, 1) You're missing context, when do you set $hotelProBookingURL? 2) Your question seems to describe errors from two different states of your code, make sure you post the code that corresponds to your most recent error 3) Please point out which line is throwing the exception; sometimes that can be unclear.

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys. Actually I now realized that when I remove "//" form define.php
                      
from 
// Test server
// $hotelProBookingURL =

to
// Test server
 $hotelProBookingURL =           

then I can communicate with the wsdl server but shows the url in the front page

Answer (score 3):

According to the exception,

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: ... 'uri' option is required in nonWSDL mode

So, referring to the [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) documentation:

> #### options
>
> An array of options. If working in WSDL mode, this parameter is optional. If working in non-WSDL mode, the location and uri options must be set, where location is the URL of the SOAP server to send the request to, and uri is the target namespace of the SOAP service.

Looking at your code:

```
$client = new SoapClient($hotelProBookingURL, array('trace' => 1));
```

What's the value of $hotelProBookingURL?  If it's null, you're missing necessary options, causing your error.

Comment: thanks a lot Brad; it's actually 1. I have the feeling that something else "changed" because I managed to make a booking once and then gave fatal error again

Comment: What's 1?  Hopefully not the value of `$hotelProBookingURL`.  If your code keeps changing, please simply place your most recent code and error in your question.

Comment: It is for array('trace' => 1)); not null. I have commented the defines.php file // Live server

$hotelProBookingURL = "http://api.hotelspro.com/4.1/hotel/b2bHotelSOAP.wsdl";

// Test server

$hotelProBookingURL = "http://api.hotelspro.com/4.1_test/hotel/b2bHotelSOAP.wsdl";
and I solve the issue with booking. However, the problem now is that I get the url of the test server in the front site (like in http://fluxuryworld.com/HotelCollection/bookhotel/oberoi-mauritius-2/ )